# Salvar dados de um arquivo txt em uma struct como inteiro ou manipular o struct. C

Tags: c, arquivo, struct, char, int

Eu tenho um arquivo txt que segue o modelo abaixo. Eu quero salvar o saldo como int, mas com fgets eu não consigo isto. Eu estou querendo salvar como int, pois depois que os dados são pegos o programa ordena eles com base no saldo. Tem algum outro modo de fazer isso???

```
nome
conta
saldo

Kelsen da Silva
54432
3456
William Malvezzi
67890
154998
Fulano de Tal 
14441
23987
```

O código que deu para pegar os dados e imprimir está assim.

```
struct conta{
  char nome[100];
  char conta[4];
  char saldo[10];
};

int main(){

int i = 0;
struct conta contas[10];
FILE *file = fopen("string.txt", "r");

while(!feof(file)){
    fgets(contas[i].nome, sizeof(contas[i].nome), file);
    fgets(contas[i].conta, sizeof(contas[i].conta), file);
    fgets(contas[i].saldo, sizeof(contas[i].saldo), file);
    i++;
  };

fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: Um detalhe que tem que observar: uma string em C é uma cadeia de caracteres seguida do caractere terminador '\0'. Assim `char conta[4];` poderá armazenar uma string de até **3** caracteres (acrescido do terminador '\0'). Pelos seus dados (ex.: 54432) você precisaria declarar `char conta[6];` ou maior caso a conta possa ter mais algarismos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando que você já consegue obter os dados de saldo na variável **conta[i].saldo**, basta transformar o valor dessa variável de **string** para **integer**, utilizando a função [atoi()](https://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-type-casting/c-atoi-function/). Para isso, você precisará de uma nova variável do tipo **integer** para alocar o resultado dessa função. Sugiro adicionar uma nova variável na sua **struct conta**, por exemplo, **int saldo_int**.
Aproveitando o seu laço de atribuição da variável com os dados do arquivo, pode-se adicionar, logo abaixo do último **fgets()** a função atoi(), da seguinte forma:

```
while(!feof(file)){
  fgets(contas[i].nome, sizeof(contas[i].nome), file);
  fgets(contas[i].conta, sizeof(contas[i].conta), file);
  fgets(contas[i].saldo, sizeof(contas[i].saldo), file);
  contas[i].saldo_int = atoi(contas[i].saldo);
  i++;
};
```

Assim feito, basta implementar a **ordenação** que deseja com base na variável **contas.saldo_int**.

**Observação**: como não foi informado, caso essa estrutura do **struct** deva ser fixa dessa forma (3 variáveis com esses exatos nomes), são necessárias duas mudanças. Primeiro, para permitir a ordenação, o campo **saldo** deve ser declarado como **int**; e segundo, deve ser criada uma **variável auxiliar** para realizar o trabalho que sua variável contas[i].saldo está fazendo (receber dados do arquivo) e em seguida atribuir seu valor nesta variável através da função atoi() comentada acima (como dito anteriormente, esta variável deve ser declarada como inteiro dentro da struct). Caso a estrutura possa ser mudada, basta ignorar essa observação e implementar o código acima.